# Is it possible to do this sort in ElasticSearch, without using script_score?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do this sort with a single ElasticSearch query (without resorting to using script_score):

1. Objects with region=DE and language=de, sorted by createdDate.
2. Objects with region=DE and any language, sorted by createdDate.
3. Objects with any region and language=en, sorted by createdDate.

At first, I thought I could do a function_score query (boost_mode: replace, score_mode: sum) and:

1. If region=DE and language=de, set score to 300000000000000 + createdDate.
2. If region=DE and language!=de, set score to 200000000000000 + createdDate.
3. If region!=DE and language=en, set score to 100000000000000 + createdDate.

I can add the createdDate to the score by using field_value_factor. But I can't find a function_score [function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#score-functions) to add 300000000000000 to the score if region=DE and language=de.

Is it possible to do this without using script_score?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
{
    "sort": [
        {"_score": "desc"},
        {"created_date": "desc"}
    ],
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "minimum_should_match": 1,
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "constant_score": {
                                "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                            { "term": { "region": "DE" } },
                                            { "term": { "language": "de" } }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "boost": 3
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "constant_score": {
                                "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                            { "term": { "region": "DE" } },
                                            { "not": { "term": { "language": "de" } } }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "boost": 2
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "constant_score": {
                                "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                            { "not": { "term": { "region": "DE" } } },
                                            { "term": { "language": "en" } }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "boost": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```